# Cross reference text in word

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I have a Word document which include several tables for different items.

I would like to refer in the main body text to the items directly (e.g.

> See Item 1 for further reference

).

I don't want to create a caption for each table saying "Item 1" and then referring the Table caption because it would refer to Table 273 (which contains Item 1). It is much neater if I can refer to Item 1 directly.

I have seen it done in other documents but I cannot remember how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can create a bookmark for the items.

1. Select the item
2. Insert > Links > Bookmark
3. Give your bookmark a name that is meaningful
4. Where you want this, use the Cross-Reference feature and cross-reference bookmarks.

This will give you plain text which will act as a hyperlink without being so marked.

### Alternative method - a HyperLink

Same as 1-3 above except for your cross-reference, Insert > Links > Hyperlink. Link to a place in the document, a bookmark. You can type what you want and it will show up in typical hyperlink format.

You can also create hyperlinks or cross-references to anything formatted using a built-in heading.

### Cross-References and Hyperlinks are also available for any of the built-in heading styles.

These can be formatted to look like ordinary text and can be [assigned to keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330).

Here is [my information on inserting cross-references](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#crossreferences) in my page on Complex Documents.